# Memory issue while replacing text Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, string, xcode

In my current App I need to create PDF documents. To do that I created an HTML file and load it in to a String.

```
 let pathBundle = Bundle.main.path(forResource: path, ofType: "html")

    do {
        // Load the invoice HTML template code into a String variable.
        var HTMLContent = try String(contentsOfFile: pathBundle!)
 }
catch{}
```

After that I replace keywords in that String with the values that I need to have in there like this:

```
HTMLContent = HTMLContent.replacingOccurrences(of: "#KEY#", with:  value)
```

I also do this with images with base64:

```
 let tstr64:String = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
     HTMLContent = HTMLContent.replacingOccurrences(of: "#IMAGE01#", with: "data:image/png;base64," +  tstr64)
```

This all works quite good but after we changed the .html file to a better (and quite bigger) version we get the following error:

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

Does anybody know a solution to avoid this memory issue?

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix this? I'm facing similar issue.

Comment: @SquareBox The problem was that the image data was invalid so it was too big. Because this image was loaded up to three times in the html it went too big for memory.